# Property 'picker' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'TimeRangePickerProps'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I'm trying to use the new `RangePicker` for `TimePicker` of antd v4 but it's giving me an error. I looked at their documentation, nothing about `picker` property is documented. The weird thing is, it only happens in my dev environment. I tried to reproduce it in codesandbox but I couldn't. Here's a screenshot of the error.

[image: Missing picker prop error]

Can anybody help me pls...

**UPDATE**
As requested, this basically the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TimePicker, Form } from 'antd';

const { RangePicker } = TimePicker;

const Test = () => {
   const [form] = Form.useForm()

   return (
      <Form form={form}>
         <div>
            <Form form={form}>
               <Form.Item>
                  <RangePicker />
               </Form.Item>
            </Form>
         </div>
      </Form>
   )
}

export default Test
```

Comment: Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: What is `picker`?

Comment: @wentjun it's a prop the linter is asking which is not in antd's documentation

Comment: @adredx please refer to my solution!

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other props of `TimePicker`'s `RangePicker` is actually stated on the common [RangePicker API documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#Common-API), as explained on the [TimePicker documentation](https://ant.design/components/time-picker/#RangePicker).

> Same props from RangePicker of DatePicker.

The RangePicker interface is probably extended from the common interface, and they did not omit it for the below scenario, which is kinda strange.

This is how RangePicker should be written:

```
<RangePicker picker='time' />
```

Comment: Wrong! `Type '"week"' is not assignable to type '"time"'.ts(2322)`

Comment: Sorry, it was a type. It should be `picker='week' `

Comment: Pls refer to my reply above your comment. That's the error I'm getting.

Comment: The documentation you're linking is wrong. This is the correct one:https://ant.design/components/time-picker/. TimePicker has a prop called RangePicker as well.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Let me update my code. Seems like the full props is in fact stated on the link I have posted. The only difference is that, `RangePicker` for requires the `picker` props to be of `time`